# Implementing morphological bridging with Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am doing some image processing with Python and following a paper trying to implement a solution, and in this paper the author says he uses morphological bridging to connect some segments, but he doesn't show how. Searching on internet I didn't find anything about how morphological bridging works or how to implement it. Does anyone has any reference I can use to implement this morphological bridging?

edit1: 
In the image below (sorry for the low-quality image) you can see the blood vessels of a retina image and a lot of segments. Those segments are part of the blood vessels, so they need to be connected

Blood Vessels Extraction:

[image: Blood Vessels Extraction]

Comment: Can you show us an actual pictorial example?  My best guess is to do a morphological closing.  Please show us an example from the paper for us to look at.

Comment: Probably is the _"bridge"_ operation like described [here (for Matlab)](https://it.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwmorph.html)

Comment: Yes, there is a matlab function to do it, but I need to do this with python.

Comment: _"I didn't find anything about how morphological bridging works or how to implement it. Does anyone has any reference I can use to implement this morphological bridging"_ but you know about the matlab function which contains the algorithm you can use as reference to implement this operation?

Comment: I just found that matlab has a function for it, I don't know how it works

Comment: _"sets 0-valued pixels to 1 if they have two nonzero neighbors that are not connected"_

Comment: Please let us know the method you function you found in Matlab. There is no point if you find the answer and keep it for yourself.

Comment: the matlab function I found is the same that Miki sent the link

Comment: @Miki's comment extracted from MATLAB's docs says it all. Try that method and let us know how it goes.

Comment: I implemented the solution here https://github.com/srv-gabriel/brigding

Answer (score 0):

Method with python implemented as MatLab description of bridging:

https://github.com/srv-gabriel/bridging/blob/master/bridging.py